# What is the preferred way to denote orders of magnitude in BTC?

Tags: currencies, terminology

If I have 36,235.97 BTC, would I shorten that by writing that I have *36.2k BTC* or would I write *36.2 kBTC*?

It seems that latter is proper for SI units, while the former is used more often for money, at least in the U.S.

Comment: You could always use tonal Bitcoins;)

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but it's probably the quirkiest and least useful of a legitimate question I've seen in a long time! ;)

Comment: If I had 36,235,97 BTC I wouldn't tell anyone.  If anyone asks I'ld say that I have 98.76 bitcoins but even then most of them are in cold storage so don't even try.

Comment: I had some fun writing this [guide to denominations](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/FAQ#What_do_I_call_the_various_denominations_of_Bitcoins.3F) a while back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write 36.2K BTC.

On the other hand, if I had 0.0362 BTC, I would write 36.2 mBTC.

Comment: mBTC, omg, that's horrible, readability just died!

Comment: @Lohoris: Are you the one who downvoted me? For mentioning mBTC, the accepted abbreviation for millibitcoin which should become more standard as BTC price increases? (Which is also used by bitcoin-qt by the way)

Comment: In other words you've downvoted a correct answer because you don't like the facts mentioned in it.

Comment: I think it's horrible, so I've downvoted it. Nothing personal.

Comment: mBTC ftw. :) also, 3.62 bitcents (aka cBTC :) ) works.

Comment: Given that the community [have agreed on an answer to this](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/FAQ#What_do_I_call_the_various_denominations_of_Bitcoins.3F), I'm upvoting. SI units FTW.

Comment: There's also this chart that also includes the tonal prefixes: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Units

Comment: The common people will use what everyone else is using. Which means that if we establish a convention of SI, everyone will use SI. That doesn't preclude the possibility of a shortened name or fancy symbol though.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely 36.2k BTC.

As you noticed, it's what is most used for money anyway.

And, for the record, I'd never short lesser units as @Meni suggested, because it would only cause confusion: it's not a SI unit we are talking about, it's money, and money uses different conventions.

Comment: Then what, in your opinion, is the convention for writing 0.0000063 BTC?

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld 6.3u BTC? Unless you can use a mu letter.

Comment: @ThePiachu: That's what I think (though probably should be 6.3 uBTC). I'm challenging Lohoris' reluctance to use small SI prefixes.

Comment: 0.0000063 BTC, until they are valued enough it will be commonplace to exchange such amounts.

Answer (score -1):

As BTC is written on the right side of the amount, it suggests being more like a science quantity, rather than a currency, which usually have their signs on the left side. So I'd argue that if you want to write 36,235.97 BTC, you should do it like 36.2 kBTC, but if you wanted to write BTC36,235.97, you'd write BTC36.2k. I haven't seen the latter version used, so probably the first one would be preferred, but then again, nobody would notice anyway...

Comment: Not a valid comparison. BTC is supposed to be a currency code like USD, not a currency symbol. AFAIK people say "100 USD", not "USD100".

Comment: I googled "usd100": About 1,680,000 results, and then "100usd": About 1,520,000 results

Comment: @HighlyIrregular: Interesting.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular: Oh, but "100 USD" (with space, exact) gives 14,900,000 results. And you do know the number of results is mostly made up (or a very wild guess at best), right?

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld I wasn't claiming it was reliable, but there's obviously a lot of variation out there in notation (and for what it's worth "100 USD" gives me a bit over 5m results, rather than 14m!)